# Cryptopp: Get the padded string of input to the cipher

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I am currently struggling around with the crypto++ lib for c++. All I want is to get the padded input to the cipher. I have the following snippet to encrypt a string "plain":

```
CryptoPP::StringSource(plain, true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(e, new CryptoPP::StringSink(cipher), CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::DEFAULT_PADDING));
```

where e is a cipher as:

```
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::SPECK128 >::Encryption e;
```

I can output the cipher text with the following snippet:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource(cipher, true, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::FileSink(std::cout)));
```

What I need is to get the padded version of the string "plain". Is there anybody who can give me a hint to use the StreamTransformationFilter to get the output of the padded input string?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::NO_PADDING`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_block_padding_scheme_def.html#abea06c498771e8f0ad0fbbc19416a979ad929ced62ab4871b2d9b87cab0b47887) instead of removing `BlockPaddingSchemeDef` altogether during decryption. It will then not expect padding and interpret the padding as plaintext.

The padding is always within the final 16 bytes (presuming a block size of 128 bits), starting at the right. Beware that the returned bytes are usually not characters as they are below < `0x20`, which means that they are usually interpreted as control characters.

Comment: I am interested in the padded version of my input, so I want to have the padded version which will be encrypted.

Comment: Added "during decryption".